# Linear Interpolation in R with a data frame that contains 0's

Tags: r, interpolation

I'm trying to interpolate wind speed data which is currently in an hour interval to 10mins.

I'm trying to use the approx function, however I keep returning NA values. I suspect this is because the wind speed data has recorded 0's which need to be represented within the new data frame. Although approx doesn't know how to deal with it. Any ideas on how to fix this? Or an R package that could help instead?

Any insight would be amazing!

```
#load windspeed data
WJune <- read.csv("WindJune.csv")
```

This is how the first 40 rows of `WJune` look like:

```
structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1L, 2L, 13L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 25L, 26L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L), .Label = c("1/6/18 0:00", 
"1/6/18 1:00", "1/6/18 10:00", "1/6/18 11:00", "1/6/18 12:00", 
"1/6/18 13:00", "1/6/18 14:00", "1/6/18 15:00", "1/6/18 16:00", 
"1/6/18 17:00", "1/6/18 18:00", "1/6/18 19:00", "1/6/18 2:00", 
"1/6/18 20:00", "1/6/18 21:00", "1/6/18 22:00", "1/6/18 23:00", 
"1/6/18 3:00", "1/6/18 4:00", "1/6/18 5:00", "1/6/18 6:00", "1/6/18 7:00", 
"1/6/18 8:00", "1/6/18 9:00", "2/6/18 0:00", "2/6/18 1:00", "2/6/18 10:00", 
"2/6/18 11:00", "2/6/18 12:00", "2/6/18 13:00", "2/6/18 14:00", 
"2/6/18 15:00", "2/6/18 2:00", "2/6/18 3:00", "2/6/18 4:00", 
"2/6/18 5:00", "2/6/18 6:00", "2/6/18 7:00", "2/6/18 8:00", "2/6/18 9:00"
), class = "factor"), wnd = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.13, 5.33, 
4.11, 4.88, 5.08, 4.23, 5.45, 5.33, 4.08, 2.84, 0.61, 0.16, 0.17, 
0, 0, 0.06, 0.02, 0.11, 0.02, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.21, 0.1, 2.9, 
3.56, 2.9, 3.2, 3.96, 4.19), solar = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
61.9, 163.4, 398.2, 1962.9, 2272.4, 2322.5, 1963.7, 1453.1, 1027.6, 
213.5, 9.3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 54, 120.6, 
320.3, 1987.2, 2281.9, 2328.9, 2141.8, 1733.1), rain = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
40L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I tried:

```
#Creating an output at 10min intervals
Wmins <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-06-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2018-06-30 23:00:00"), by=600)
Wmins

#Interpolate values using approx function
Wout <- approx(WJune$datetime, WJune$wnd, xout=Wmins, method="linear", ties=mean, yleft=0, rule=1)
```

Approx. output after converting to correct format, this constant value was seen for the whole data set. If anyone has any insight into why this is happening that would be greatly appreciated 
    `> dput(Wout$y)
    c(0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 
    0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49)`

Comment: If you don't want `NA` values, why you set `rule=1`? Read `?approx`.

Comment: Using      rule=2 provides only one value of 0.49

Comment: You should share your data, otherwise it's difficult to give any help. Post the output of `dput(WJune)`.

Comment: You need to convert your `datetime` column to `POSIXct`: `WJune$datetime<-as.POSIXct(WJune$datetime,format="%d/%m/%y %H:%M")`, then proceed with the interpolation.